# Is there a notion of best $\mathbb{K}$-approximations where $\mathbb{K}$ is an algebraic number field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, reference-request, field-theory, diophantine-approximation

A known approximation of $\pi$ is $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}=\color{green}{3.14}\color{red}{6264...}$ But recently I came across a refinement of this approximation
$$\pi\approx\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\frac{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}{68}=\color{green}{3.14159}\color{red}{0292...}$$
Knowing this, I tried to find interesting approximations of $\pi$ on $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and I've been able to obtain
$$\boxed{\pi\approx\frac{42(132\sqrt{2}+375\sqrt{3}-19^2)}{5\left(\left(5^2+2^2\cdot\sqrt{2}\right)\left(10^2+3^2\cdot\sqrt{3}\right)-2273\right)}=\color{green}{3.1415926535897}\color{red}{63336...}}$$
But this made me thinking:

> **Q:** Similar to how we know that the *best* $\mathbb{Q}$-aproximations of a given real number $x>0$ are given via the partial fractions of its continued fraction representation, is there any notion of *best* $\mathbb{K}$-approximations where $\mathbb{K}$ is an algebraic number field (i.e. a finite field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$) like $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ or $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$?

I know that, for $\mathbb{Q}$, we can say that $\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}$ is a best approximation of $x>0$ if
$$\forall a'/b'\in\mathbb{Q}\text{ with }b'\leq b\text{ we have }\left|x-\frac{a}{b}\right|\leq\left|x-\frac{a'}{b'}\right|$$
However, we can't extend this to (say) $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ naively expressing numbers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ as $\frac{a+b\sqrt{2}}{c}$ since $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{2})=\{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense on $\mathbb{R}$ so, for a fixed $c$, we can find $\frac{a+b\sqrt{2}}{c}$ arbitrarily close to $x>0$.

Comment: The norm wouldn’t be sufficient, since it can take infinitely many times the value $1$. The height would be a better candidate. The keyword you might be looking for is Diophantine approximation. See also Roth’s Theorem (or Faltings’ Theorem!).

Comment: We can also approximate $\pi$ (or any other real number) very well with expressions of the form $$\frac{a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}}{d+e\sqrt{2}+f\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: @Aphelli, Of course! Pell's equation

Answer (score 1):

You can define best approximations in any $\mathbb Q$-vector space, and in particular in any finite field extension of the rational numbers as follows.

Let $K=\{q_0+a_1 q_1 +\dots + a_n q_n:q_i\in\mathbb Q\}$ be a $\mathbb Q$-vector space where $(1, a_1, \dots, a_n)$ is linearly independent so $K$ is $n+1$ dimensional. A vector $v\in \mathbb Z^{n+1}$ is a best approximation for the vector $(1, a_1, \dots, a_n)$ if
$$|v\cdot (1, a_1, \dots, a_n)|< |w\cdot (1, a_1, \dots, a_n)|$$
for all $w\in\mathbb Z^{n+1}$ with $\lVert w\rVert<\lVert v\rVert$ for some norm $\lVert \cdot\rVert$. Since all the norms in $\mathbb R^d$ are equivalent, it doesn't really matter which one you choose.

This has a nice geometric interpretation, as you're looking for lattice points near a hyperplane going through the origin, and no other rational points. And you want the distance from your lattice points to the hyperplane to be small compared to the norm of the lattice point.

To approximate a number other than 0, say $\pi$ as in your example you can use $Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)=\{a+b\sqrt 2+c\sqrt 3+d\sqrt 6:a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Q\}=V$ so a best approximation is $x\in\mathbb Z^4$ such that
$$|\pi-x\cdot (1, \sqrt 2, \sqrt 3, \sqrt 6)|<|\pi-y\cdot (1, \sqrt 2, \sqrt 3, \sqrt 6)|$$
for all $y$ with $\lVert y\rVert<\lVert x\rVert$.

You can find references for this type of thing by searching for approximation of linear forms. And there's an algorithm for producing good approximations called the Jacobi-Perron algorithm.

Comment: You say that it doesn't really matter which norm do we choose but that would be right if we only cared about topology. However, this is not the case. For instance, the norms $\lVert a+b\sqrt{2}\rVert_1=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\lVert a+b\sqrt{2}\rVert_2=\sqrt{a^2+9b^2}$ are certainly equivalent but on the first one $1+\sqrt{2}$ is a best approximation of $\pi$ while on the second one it is not as $3$ is better. This is because, on the second one, $\sqrt{2}$ is much more expensive. So it really matters which norm do we choose.

Comment: Moreover that would only give a notion of *integral* approximations over a finite number field $\mathbb{K}$. So, given your setup, it doesn't make sense to ask whether $\frac{69}{68}\sqrt{2}+\frac{67}{68}\sqrt{3}$ is a best $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$-approximation of $\pi$ as it is not of the form $v\cdot(1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6})$ where $v\in\mathbb{Z}^4$.

Answer (score 1):

> Similar to how we know that the best $\mathbf Q$-approximations of a given real number $x>0$ are given via the partial fractions of its continued fraction representation

It depends on what you mean by the word "via".  Each partial fraction $p/q$ in the continued fraction of $x$ is the best rational approximation to $x$ up to denominator $q$, but if you pick a denominator $d$ that is *not* among the denominators of the partial fractions, then the best rational approximation to $x$ up to denominator $d$ might not be a partial fraction.

**Example**.  The partial fractions of the continued fraction of $\pi$ are $3$, $22/7$, $333/106$, $\ldots$ and the best rational approximation to $\pi$ among fractions with denominator $\leq 100$ is not $3$ or $22/7$: it is $311/99 =  3.141414\ldots$.

The best rational approximations to $x$ up to any denominator at all will be among the partial fractions and intermediate fractions to the continued fraction of $x$.